# Cumulative-Sum-to-the-End for each element in the array

Tags: python, arrays, algorithm, numpy, cumsum

Suppose I have an array `a = array([a0, a1,..., an])`. For every element in the array, I need to find all cumulative sums in the direction from left to right. Thus, for `n=2` I have to find

`a0, a0+a1, a0+a1+a2, a1, a1+a2, a2`.

The obvious approach is the following:

```
list_of_sums = [np.cumsum(a[i:]) for i in xrange(n+1)]
```

I wonder if there exists a more efficient way to do this. The issue is that `n` may be quite large and in addition I want to broadcast this for many different arrays `a` of the same length. Unfortunately, I did not succeed to create a vectorized function for this.

Another problem is how to store all these sums. Instead of using list, we can represent all the data as `2D` array `A`, where in the first column `A[:,0]` I have all the sums with `a0` as the first term, in the second column `A[:,1]` I have all the sums with `a1` as the first term,  and so on. This gives us `(n+1)x(n+1)` matrix, half elements of which are zeros (the right lower triangle). On the other hand, this requires in 2 times more memory than list use, or force us to use sparse matrices that may be overkill.

Comment: Have you tried to use the axis parameter of np.cumsum for vectorizing it for many arrays? Storing the results seems to be the biggest problems. Anything i try causes the machine to hang for large arrays and large n

Comment: @M4rtini Sure, for many arrays I've used `np.cumsum` with axis parameter.